# How can I find d knowing c, n, e in RSA?

Tags: rsa, factoring

If I know $n,e,c$ can I find $d$ in RSA? ($n = 3174654383$ and $e = 65537$ $c=2487688703$)

I saw this $d=(1/e)\bmod\varphi$ but if the numbers are getting bigger it can be hard to get $d$ in that way and now I'm calculating it but still cant find yet.

And I saw another RSA challenge where I need to find $p$ $q$ used for $n$. And in my case because $n$ is so big, I think it would be hard to find the proper $p,q$.

Comment: Comment: $c$ is of no use to compute a value of $d$. One way is $d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\varphi$, and the hardest part of it is computing $\varphi$ \[the rest can use the (half-)[extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures)\]. We usually use $\varphi\gets(p-1)(q-1)$, with $n$ constructed as the product of (large, random, secret, distinct, prime) $p$ and $q$. With proper choice of $p$ and $q$, they are hard to find from $n$. With $d$ and $n$ [or $p,q,e$], one can decipher $c$.

Answer (score 2):

3174654383 is a very small number & can be factored using a lot of different methods.

Here is an online factoring page & it factored it in seconds - https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/prime-factors.php

3174654383 = 52673 x 60271

The page also explains how it is done.

Your n is 32 bit.
In actual RSA, n is typically 1024 or 2048 bits & it's not easy to factor. If it was easy, then RSA wouldn't be secure.